# How do I set up a second 5GHz N-Only network with DD-WRT?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dd-wrt, wireless-access-point

I have a Linksys WRT610N v2 running DD-WRT v24-sp2 (mega) - build 14896. I'm trying to set up two access points on the device. One 802.11g network for most of the computers and wireless devices in my house, and one 802.11n AP for a computer which is farther away.

I can get the first AP (wl0) working with the following settings:
Wireless mode: AP
Wireless network mode: NG mixed
Channel: Auto
Width: 40Mhz
Control Channel: upper
Ack timing: 2000
Network config: bridged

But the second AP (wl1) doesn't seem to work. At one point it was visible on my Mac Pro (the machine farther away) but when I connected to it, it just timed out. These are the current settings (which aren't showing the SSID):

Wireless mode: AP
Wireless network mode: N-Only (5 GHz)
Channel: 56 - 5.280 GHz
Width: 40 MHz
Control Channel: upper
Ack timing: 2000
Network config: bridged

Both have security mode set to WPA2 Personal, with AES.

Anyone have any experience with setting up DD-WRT and this router?

Answer (score 3):

I'm noticing a few problems with your planned setup. Some of them may just be problems with DD-WRT's UI (which I'm not familiar with), but I'm just going to list them all out here.

1. There's no value in turning off 802.11n in the 2.4GHz band. There seems to be a myth that you should for some reason turn off 802.11n in 2.4GHz if you only expect B/G devices to use it, but that's a myth and I have no idea where it comes from. On the contrary, you should leave it on so that your dual-band N devices can choose to do N in 2.4GHz when it suits their needs. For example, you can often get better data rates at longer ranges with 2.4GHz, so which it's better to use 5GHz when you're close, it's often better to use 2.4GHz when you're farther away. *I note that your actual configuration you pasted in shows that you weren't trying to disable N in 2.4GHz, even though that seems to differ from what you said you were trying to do in the previous paragraph, so maybe I misunderstood what you were saying in that paragraph.*
2. For 2.4GHz, why does it just say NG-mixed instead of "NGB-mixed"? Leaving the old B rates enabled for clients that choose to use them is a good idea. Sometimes you can get 1mbps connectivity out at the edge of range where the lowest G rate (6mbps) would fail you. Leaving B rates enabled for the sake of even super-modern clients that choose to use them is usually a good idea, especially if you care about range, which it seems like you do.
3. Again for 2.4GHz, why does it say `Width: 40MHz`? The 802.11n spec has no 40MHz-only mode. It has a 20MHz-only mode and a 20/40 automatic mode. I don't know whether this setting means standards-compliant 20/40 or means some nonstandard 40MHz-only mode. Also note that using 40MHz-wide channels in 2.4GHz takes up an awful lot of the band, and doesn't leave much room for other users of the band, such as your Bluetooth gear, Wii remotes, etc.  It's considered "good neighbor" policy to only use 20MHz-wide channels in 2.4GHz.
4. Again for 2.4GHz, why does it say `Channel: Auto`, `Width: 40MHz`, and `Control Channel: upper`? Shouldn't either the control channel or the width be `auto` in case it wants to pick channels 1-4, where you can't have the control channel above the extension channel? Or does this combination of settings just rule out channels 1-4 all together? Or does it automatically switch you to 20MHz mode if it wants to choose channels 1-4? It seems unclear from what you've reported here.
5. For 5GHz, why N-only mode? You should leave 802.11a enabled if you want the best rates at range, so that your Mac Pro or other machines can choose to use those legacy rates that work at longer distances than the N-only rates do. Maybe your Mac Pro is far enough away that it can't do N rates reliably, and it would do better if it had the option of doing A rates. For that matter, it would probably do even better if you used the same, non-hidden SSID on both networks, so that your Mac Pro could choose to use the 2.4GHz network when that was a better choice. I understand the desire to second-guess your devices' band choices, but if you didn't manage to make it work while second-guessing, maybe it's time to see if they work for themselves when you aren't second-guessing.
6. In 5GHz, why is it allowing you to manually pick a DFS (radar) channel? I see from your profile that you're in London. The UK follows the European (ETSI) RF regulations, and I believe the ETSI regulations require that implementations that allow use of DFS channels must not allow you to specify the channel. Implementations that want to be able to use DFS channels can only do so if you leave channel selection on "Auto", and at every boot/reset time they must randomly choose a channel, spend 60 seconds only listening to detect radar pulses on that channel, and only start using the channel if they didn't detect radar in that 60 seconds. So I guess it's possible that this channel didn't work because it detected radar pulses on that channel. You'll probably be better off leaving this channel selection on Auto.

Answer (score 0):

I have the Linksys E3000 which also runs dual band, I had trouble with this setup too using dd-wrt.

I'm running DD-WRT v24-sp2 (12/24/10) mega (SVN revision 15962).

It seems to be related to how it handles security (though this is just an observation rather than fact). I was unable to have security on both WLAN's at the same time.

My solution was to setup the 2.4GHz band with no security, I have it secured using a hidden SSID and the MAC filtering capabilities of the firmware only letting pre-approved addresses connect to the router.

On the 5GHz I have the exact same settings as yourself.

I know it's not a great answer but it works. I'm hoping they'll fix it in some newer firmware but I've always had issues with wifi and dd-wrt (previously on a WRT120N and currently on an E3000) so I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: damn, doesn't seem to work with mine. I feel like this build is very flaky with this router. Hopefully they'll resolve things soon, but I know what you mean.

Comment: Just a little word of warning: hidden SSID and MAC filtering are not effective means of securing a WiFi network, with the appropriate tools it's a very quick job to find the network and clone the MAC address of one of the partecipating clients. You probably knew this already but I thought it was worth pointing it out anyway.

Comment: Indeed it is not the same nor incredibly effective if faced off against a malicious attacker, I'm working on the assumption that I've never given anyone any cause to attempt to breach my wifi, the fact that the SSID is not broadcasting and only I know what it is makes it difficult to guess (though not impossible to brute force) and the fact that my MAC addresses aren't readily available are enough of a deterrent for any random wifi hacker that might pass my home.

Answer (score -1):

DD-WRT support for 5.0 GHz is suspect. For some router versions there seems to be clear indication 5.0 GHz is not supported, for some it will NEVER be supported.

Before wasting time with 5.0 Ghz, please try and find out if it is supported for your router of choice. Honestly, I could not get a clear answer, so I went with Tomato instead and have not looked back.